# mongodb constantly in CrashLoopBackOff in AKS kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, azure-aks

i am trying to bring up a stateful set of MongoDB but it keeps crashing .
i started this configuration on azure VM instances in a custom k8s cluster and there was no problem.
now when I start my statefulset on AKS this problem occures.

here's my YAML:

STATEFULSET:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: dbs
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo
      environment: test
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo
        args: ["--dbpath","/data/db"]
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
              - mongo
              - --disableImplicitSessions
              - --eval
              - "db.adminCommand('ping')"
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 6
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
              - mongo
              - --disableImplicitSessions
              - --eval
              - "db.adminCommand('ping')"
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 100
          timeoutSeconds: 50
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 6
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-creds
              key: username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-creds
              key: password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: "mongo-data-dir"
          mountPath: "/data/db"
      volumes:
      - name: "mongo-data-dir"
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-mongo
```

STORAGE CLASS AND PVC:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-azurefile
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - actimeo=30
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-mongo
  namespace: dbs
spec: 
  storageClassName: my-azurefile
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 32Gi
```

kubectl describe pod mongo-0:

```
Name:         mongo-0
Namespace:    dbs
Priority:     0
Node:         aks-agentpool-16784693-vmss000003/10.224.0.4
Start Time:   Mon, 02 May 2022 11:16:36 +0300
Labels:       controller-revision-hash=mongo-656569fcf9
              environment=test
              role=mongo
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mongo-0
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.16
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.16
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/mongo
Containers:
  mongo:
    Container ID:  containerd://a6ca7501be49fd806695004cc8f5aa53299caa2a27a60c964c2366f011441cb5
    Image:         mongo
    Image ID:      docker.io/library/mongo@sha256:981c74be62db9c39e7ebb4eaa8e1c51f40b905bb00285e8463c88c174da80674
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      --dbpath
      /data/db
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    14
      Started:      Mon, 02 May 2022 11:18:25 +0300
      Finished:     Mon, 02 May 2022 11:18:26 +0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Liveness:       exec [mongo --disableImplicitSessions --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=90s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:      exec [mongo --disableImplicitSessions --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=60s timeout=50s period=100s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:  <set to the key 'username' in secret 'mongo-creds'>  Optional: false
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'password' in secret 'mongo-creds'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /data/db from mongo-data-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-hf999 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  mongo-data-dir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pvc-mongo
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-hf999:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m13s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned dbs/mongo-0 to aks-agentpool-16784693-vmss000003
  Normal   Pulled     2m13s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "mongo" in 422.356002ms
  Normal   Pulled     2m11s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "mongo" in 183.605227ms
  Normal   Pulled     110s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "mongo" in 189.790424ms
  Normal   Created    75s (x4 over 2m13s)  kubelet            Created container mongo
  Normal   Started    75s (x4 over 2m13s)  kubelet            Started container mongo
  Normal   Pulling    75s (x4 over 2m13s)  kubelet            Pulling image "mongo"
  Normal   Pulled     75s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "mongo" in 189.887371ms
  Warning  BackOff    64s (x9 over 2m9s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: I believe you also need a persistent volume, not just the storage class and the claim... Can you also include the logs? `kubectl logs -n dbs po/mongo-0`

Comment: yes that was it, it used to have a pv but I removed it opting for sc provisioned pv. thanks you so much